# db.contraints() is not known in higher version of Neo4j. Error while using GraphXR to save to database

Tags: neo4j, cypher, config, opencypher, neo4j-plugin

I am using GraphXR with Neo4j. When trying to save the graph to neo4j, I am presented with the following error:-
There is no procedure name 'db.constraints()'.

I am using v5.3.0. I know that the above procedure is deprecated but is there a workaround for the same or can I roll back to a previous version where the procedure name is present.

I have tried to check and operate on config file but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the Cypher [SHOW CONSTRAINTS](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/#constraints-syntax-list) clause in place of the `db.constraints` procedure.

And there is also now a [SHOW INDEXES](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/#indexes-list-indexes) to replace the `db.indexes` procedure.

Comment: Actually I wanted to use GraphXR but while saving the work to neo4j i encountered this error. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: GraphXR needs to update their Cypher logic then. Best would be to open an issue to let them know about the change cybersam just described.